# Django order_by is not ordering results of query

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework, sql-order-by

Django not ordering results by date. Am using Django-Rest-Framework to create API for app initially had a filter by on the query and after reading similar issues where people faced same problem when combining order_by and filter I removed the filter and manually filtered using a for loop but still keep getting the same results.

Initially query was:

```
progresslogs = ProgressLog.objects.filter(user__userprofile__coach=request.user).order_by('-date')
```

But reading similar issues I changed the query and filtered manually think there is an issue with using filter and order by together but am still getting the results out of order:

```
class ProgressLogAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request: Request, format=None):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.user.is_staff:
                logger.info('API: Staff {} fetched progress logs'.format(request.user.id))
                progresslogs = ProgressLog.objects.order_by('-date')
                # Below loop added to manually filter results
                filteredlogs = []
                for progress in progresslogs:
                    if progress.user.userprofile.coach == request.user:
                        filteredlogs.append(progress)

                serializer = ProgressLogSerializer(filteredlogs, many=True)
                return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

But in each case the results are coming out of order, wondering is this some bug in Django, I suppose could probably sort the results manually but am thinking this would drastically increase the time for the API call to get the results so don't really want to do this.

For reference the first 3 result from the API call are below with non applicable data replaced by a a '?' but can clearly from the date values that there not ordered at all:

```
[
  {
    "id":?,
    "user":?,
    "front_pic":"?",
    "side_pic":"?",
    "back_pic":"?",
    "weight":"?",
    "date":"2022-04-30",
    "bicep":null,
    "chest":null,
    "legs":null,
    "waist":null,
    "body_fat":null
  },
  {
     "id":?,
     "user":?,
    "front_pic":"?",
    "side_pic":"?",
    "back_pic":"?",
    "weight":"?",
    "date":"2022-03-27",
    "bicep":null,
    "chest":null,
    "legs":null,
    "waist":null,
    "body_fat":null
  },
  {
    "id":?,
    "user":?,
    "front_pic":"?",
    "side_pic":"?",
    "back_pic":"?",
    "weight":"?",
    "date":"2022-05-22",
    "bicep":null,
    "chest":null,
    "legs":null,
    "waist":null,
    "body_fat":null
  },
  ...
]
```

Django version on the server is `3.2.13`
and python version is `3.9`.

**EDIT:**
As requested here is the model and serialised:

Model:

```
class ProgressLog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    front_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='progress_front', blank=True)
    side_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='progress_side', blank=True)
    back_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='progress_back', blank=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=1, max_digits=6)
    date = models.DateField(default=get_date)
    body_fat = models.DecimalField(blank=True, decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, null=True)
    waist = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    bicep = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    chest = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    legs = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} | {}'.format(self.user.username, self.date)
```

Serializer:

```
class ProgressLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProgressLog
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'front_pic', 'side_pic', 'back_pic', 'weight', 'date', 'bicep', 'chest', 'legs', 'waist',
                  'body_fat']
```

Since posting the question last night I have tried updating Django to version `4.0.2` in case there was any bugs in the specific version of Django causing this, but results are still no ordered by date field.

Also checked by querying in the Django shell `python manage.py shell' on the server, and in this case the results are in order:

```
>>> from progress_logger.models import ProgressLog
>>> ProgressLog.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:3]
<QuerySet [<ProgressLog: ? | 2022-05-24>, <ProgressLog: ? | 2022-05-23>, <ProgressLog: ? | 2022-05-23>]>
```

Comment: Can you add your model and serializer to the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have added the model and serializer to the question.

Comment: Can you replicate this with a *much* simpler example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.   Ordering filters  are used in almost every API.

Comment: Haven't been able to replicate it, it seems to happen only in this case and testing on local machine with the above code always always returns correctly, The issue seems to happen only on the live server(which has a much larger number of records) and not with the other API calls that  are present that also use the both filters and ordered. Using a ListAPIView seems to resolve the issue, but can't understand why it happened to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't been able to solve it the way I wanted but using ListViewAPI instead seems to have fixed it, guessing the problem might be related to Django-rest-framework as the results from the interactive shell where as expected:

```
class ProgressLogAPI(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    queryset = ProgressLog.objects.filter(user__userprofile__coach=request.user).order_by('-date')
    serializer_class = ProgressLogSerializer
```